# Passing props to react navigation drawer custom header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v6

How can I pass arguments to the following custom react navigation drawer header 'NavHeader'? I want to include an icon inside the NavHeader that uses the following: `navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())`

```
function NavHeader(props) {
    return <View>...</View>;
}

<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Page1"
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: true,
    headerTransparent:false,
    header: NavHeader
  }}
>
     <Stack.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1} />
     <Stack.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `navigation` object is in the props that get passed to NavHeader.  Javascript syntax is hiding the arguments that get passed to your header; when passing a function, writing

`header: myFunction`

is the same as writing

`header: (args) => myFunction(args)`.

In other words, your screenOptions could be rewritten like this:

```js
  screenOptions={{
    // ...
    header: ({ navigation }) => <NavHeader navigation={navigation} />,
```

This is why you can use the navigation object inside the NavHeader component.
In your current NavHeader code, you can call it with `props.navigation`.

Full props that get passed to the `header`:

```js
export type StackHeaderProps = {
  /**
   * Layout of the screen.
   */
  layout: Layout;
  /**
   * Options for the back button.
   */
  back?: {
    /**
     * Title of the previous screen.
     */
    title: string;
  };
  /**
   * Animated nodes representing the progress of the animation.
   */
  progress: SceneProgress;
  /**
   * Options for the current screen.
   */
  options: StackNavigationOptions;
  /**
   * Route object for the current screen.
   */
  route: Route<string>;
  /**
   * Navigation prop for the header.
   */
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<ParamListBase>;
  /**
   * Interpolated styles for various elements in the header.
   */
  styleInterpolator: StackHeaderStyleInterpolator;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for such a good explanation and detailed answer, this is awesome!